# SciPy Convex Hull returning too many (duplicated) equations

Tags: python, scipy

Using a bunch of 12-dimensional points (see below), I'm trying to generate a ConvexHull with SciPy.

This works, but I'm getting way too many equations, 11022 to be precise, with many equations being exact duplications.

I can use NumPy to remove the duplicates (this reduces it to about 20 (!) equations), but since I also want to access `.neighbors`, I'm afraid to screw up the indexes.

Any idea why this might be happening? Is this a bug?

The points array:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

Comment: Due to decomposition of hull facets into simplices?

Comment: I think you're right @pv. -- this is somewhat strange as the object also exposes a .simplices attributes, but after going through the documentation, it does mention that "option 'Qt' is always enabled", which apparently corresponds with "triangulate". Probably this is done to be able to get the simplices out in the first place.

If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll denote it as such.